# Joomla 1.7: load module within content plugin

Tags: plugins, joomla, module

Joomla version 1.7

I have an article and a content plugin that changes content of this article.

I need to load some module in this plugin, and add to this article all html that is returned by module.

I know about `{loadposition module}` etc., but i need to do it exactly this way.

Comment: Solved.

    $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('modele_name');  
    $article->text = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module, $attribs);

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer and accept it. Perhaps with a little additional explanation for others who need the same question answering in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get some module via Joomla Api:

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule($module_name, $module_title);
```

Where **$module_name** - name of the module (for example, '**mod_custom**', '**mod_banners**')
and **$module_title** - title, which you provided in admin section for this module

Output module content:

```
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```